# Unable to delete the whole array in C++...if i try to display the array again first two values are garbage other are the same

Tags: c++, arrays, stack

My Problem is my delete function is not working.When i pushed element
 onto the stack then display it and after that if i delete the whole stack so  when i displayed it
 it should output garbage values but this is not the case it is showing the same   values again as if nothing deleted.

```
#include<iostream.h>
#include<conio.h>
template<class T>
class stack
{
    int capacity;
public:
    T *array;
    int top;
    stack(int);
    void push(T);
    T pop();  
    int stackempty();
    int stackfull();
    void display();
    void deletestack();
};

template<class T>
stack<T>::stack(int max)
{
   top=-1;
   capacity=max;
   array=new T[capacity]; 
}

template<class T>
void stack<T>::push(T data)
{  
   if(stackfull())
      cout<<"stack overflow";
   else
      array[++top]=data;
}

template<class T>
T stack<T>::pop() 
{ 
    if(stackempty())
    {
       cout<<"stack underflow"; 
       return -1;
    }
    else 
       return array[top--];
}



template<class T>
int stack<T>::stackempty()
{ 
   if(top==-1) 
      return 1;
   else 
      return 0;
}

template<class T>
int stack<T>::stackfull()
{ 
   if(top==capacity-1)
      return 1;
   else 
      return 0;
}

template<class T>
void stack<T>::display()
{
   int i;
   if(top==-1)
      cout<<"empty stack";
   else
      for(i=0;i<=top;i++)
        cout<<"\n"<<array[i];
}

template<class T>
void stack<T>::deletestack()
{
    delete []array; 
}

int main()
{
   stack<int>* S=new stack<int>(20);
   clrscr();
   S->push(5);
   S->push(10);
   S->push(15);
   S->display();
   S->deletestack();
   S->display();
   S->push(5);
   S->display();
   getch();
   return 0;
}
```

Comment: If you want to empty your stack then do `top = -1;` instead of `delete[] array;`.  The way you have designed your stack is that it is supposed to always have `capacity` items allocated, and the `top` tells how many of those items are "in use".

Answer (score 3):

That's a lot more code than necessary to illustrate this problem, but anyway... If you `delete[]` an array, it is *Undefined Behaviour* to access it again. By accessing it again, your program could do [anything at all](http://www.catb.org/jargon/html/N/nasal-demons.html).

That includes displaying the values that were already in this memory. These *are* garbage. They just happen to be garbage that looks a lot like the values your already put here. The reason this happens is that it would be extra work to go through and fill this memory with, say, zeroes. You're not allowed to look at it any more, so who cares what is there.

Comment: @nightshade Nope! It is most definitely not allowed by `c++` (or equivalent in `c` with `malloc`/`free`). The compiler will turn it into something that will execute, and the code *looks* like `c++`, but it no long *is* (valid) `c++`.

Comment: that is not what disallow means... his program didn't crash when he tried to access... giving an undefined behavior is not the same as 'not allow'... I think those undefined behaviors should be crashes instead (would help a lot in debugging)

Comment: Why should it crash? You've violated the contract. You lose. And on a technical level, why should it crash? You are accessing memory within your program's address space. If it segfaulted, that would be because you did something disallowed by the *operating system*, not the *language*.

Answer (score 0):

The line `delete []array;` in your method deletestack() will ***free*** the array of memory that the pointer called `array` is pointing at. (however free is not the same as write over it with something else)

After you call delete you return the memory to the operating system, accessing it after it was returned to the operating system is ***undefined*** behavior. Sometimes it will cause a segmentation fault and a crash and sometimes nothing bad will happen. C++ in this respect is very different from languages like Java that actively look for illegal memory access and immediately throw an exception. In C++ the programmer is expected to follow the rules and no one is checking after him.

In any case freeing the memory does not mean that it is cleared. The old values you placed in there are still there until something else will get this memory allocated and start writing to it.

There are many other issues in the code you posted that will cause weird behavior if it is used:

`stack<int>* S=new stack<int>(20);` allocated an object on the heap that is never deleted.

the class `stack` allocates an array during construction however the dtor does not release the array. A user who forgets to call `deletestack` will cause memory to leak

the class `stack` holds a reference to an allocated array however it does not have a copy-ctor or a operator= and it does not delete them.

Answer (score 0):

Imagine you owned some houses in a colony. Now you don't own them. This doesn't mean that those houses are destroyed. It may happen that the houses are there as it is. It may happen there is no house there.

Similarly, the memory alloted for your array is still there and you have its address. It may happen that location has same data or not.